# Disable a systemd service before start using cloud-init

Tags: systemd, cloud-init

I want to disable a service before systemd executes it using cloud-init.

I've tried with `runcmd` but it doesn't work even if logs of the execution are availble.

```
runcmd:
  - 'systemctl disable docker'
  - 'systemctl stop docker'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: IMHO your attempting to do the wrong thing: when a service shouldn't be started at boot, **don't enable it in the first place** ; if cloud-init should run before a particular service, because it for example needs to do prep work to ensure that all the ground work is done before the docker does get started, do just that and **configure `cloud-init` to run  before systemd starts docker** .

Comment: You are right, but I'm creating a machine from an already configure "image" and I need to disable some services before the first boot.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by  "doesn't work" ?  Does the unit's links get removed by the disable?

Comment: I can see the cloud-init logs confirming the runcmd execution but the "disabled" services are still running.